# Rally fetch timeentry item, null data is returned

Tags: extjs, rally

I have an application to fetch all hours spent on tasks/defects in many projects by all devs(so there is about 70+ users and 30 projects).
It has worked for about two years, but in last month i'm 
[getting following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5P1eJ.jpg)
Also, i have the version of the application that is fetching data only by one user and everything works fine.

Here is problem piece of code:

```
launch: function() {
                            Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
                                model: 'timeentryitem',
                                autoLoad: true,
                                listeners: { load: this._onItemsLoaded, scope: this },
                                fetch: ['TaskDisplayString', 'ProjectDisplayString', 'WorkProductDisplayString', 'WeekStartDate', 'Values', 'Task', 'WorkProduct', '_ref', 'Feature', 'FeatureDisplayString', 'FormattedID'],
                                filters: [
                                    {
                                        property: 'WeekStartDate',
                                        operator: '>=',
                                        value: self.getRangeStartDate()
                                    },
                                    {
                                        property: 'User',
                                        operator: '=',
                                        value: user
                                    }
                                ],
                                orderBy: 'WeekStartDate',
                                context: {
                                    project: '/project/' + project,
                                    projectScopeDown: false,
                                    projectScopeUp: false
                                },
                                pageSize: 500
                            });
                        },

                        _onItemsLoaded: function(store, data) {
```

Error that in `_onItemsLoaded` sometimes data is null

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` will be null if the request failed for some reason.  If you inspect your network traffic are you getting any errors in the response?

If you want more granular control of what's going on you can also not use `autoLoad` and instead call the `load` method on the store after it's created.

Then you can pass a callback function which will get called with an operation parameter which will allow you to further inspect any errors, etc.

```
var store = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', { //...
store.load({
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        if (success) {
            //yay
        } else {
            var error = operation.getError();
        }
    }
});
```